# Json Converter for Generic Types

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using json converter as shown below.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString, new ModelConfigurationJsonConverter())
```

In ReadJson method of the converter, I want to create an object of type T using the jsonString, which can be a nested type too, whats the best approach for this?

should I use reflection?

Thanks in advance

Update: Convertor code

```
 public class ModelConfigurationJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {




        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); // Since in config svc we don't WriteJson
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What did you try? I see a type parameter `<T>` there. What type did you provide for that parameter?

Comment: What is your data structure??? Why `T`?

Comment: T is a generic input Type, a class, can't define the type at compile type.

Comment: @user7784348 If you mean that `T` is an instance of `System.Type`, that's not what "generic" means in C#. It's not possible to communicate by using your own private definitions for common terms. You have to use the same definitions as everybody else. If it's actually *non-generic*, you'll have to use reflection.

Comment: Generic in c# means T will be provided at runtime, I am very clear on that. We can't say at runtime what T will be.Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

Comment: You need to **show us your code** so we can find out from the code itself what is going on here. I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to tell me. Generic in C# means type parameters such as `T` are provided at compile time at the point of use of the class or method. Elsewhere in the code, when you *write* a generic class or method, the type parameter is unknown. But at the point where you *instantiate* a generic class or *call* a generic method, the type parameter must be provided at compile time.

Comment: updated the question with Converter code.

Comment: It's not clear why you want to use your own converter though, or what problems you've run into. The `ReadJson` method is being provided the type to instantiate, so you do that by reflection - but I would question whether you really need to write your own converter at all. What will that do that the default Json.NET code wouldn't do?

Comment: I need a custom converter because the set of values of props are customized based on some logic.